# Tomcat start and stop : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, catalina

When I start tomcat from cmd like "start catalina", another cmd terminal opens and then the error given below iis taken. How can this be fixed?

```
... SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1069)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1719)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1855)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1119)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5095)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
```

Comment: is it a bare tomcat installation or do you have something deployed ? I recall having NoSuchMethodErrors for having deployed a webapp using servlet spec recent than supported ones. It's been ages since I last touched Tomcat, but ver 8 doesn't seem extremely "recent"

Comment: @BigMike I ll deploy some projects but I have not deployed yet; I am not sure but if 'm not mistaken as no server/src/shared folders and application file exist in Tomcat Home, it is not a bare tomcat installation. Even localhost:8080 not open Tomcat welcome page after "catalina start " or run is applied

Comment: then the only thing I can think of is you're using a too recent/old JVM or have some jar for a different servlet version in your classpath. Which jvm are you using ?

Comment: Java SE Runtime Environment = 1.8.0_201    JDK = 1.8.0_181,  servlet are: servlet-api, javax.servlet-3.0   @BigMike

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.NoSucMethodError comes when Java code tries to call a method which is not existed on a class, this could be either static or non static method.

Maybe solution for your issue is here

[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getContextPath()Ljava/lang/String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611777/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-servlet-servletcontext-getcontextpathljava)

[javax.servlet.ServletContext.getContextPath()Ljava/lang/String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897074/javax-servlet-servletcontext-getcontextpathljava-lang-string)